# Multiple exception logging for single problem - how to handle this?

Tags: java, logging, exception

The pattern of catch wrap and re-throw and logging at every catch-point causes several entries in the log. What do you usually do ?

Comment: I don't catch, wrap, and re-throw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any individual exception should only be logged in 1 location to avoid clogging up your logs. As long as the exception contains the original cause, you should be able to trace back to it.

Personally I do the following:
Catch checked exception at lowest level point that I can, wrap in a RuntimeException (or subclass) with the best message to detail what was happening when the exception occurred and re-throw. No logging is done at the low level. Catch the unchecked (Runtime) exceptions at a very high level, just before it can impact a user. There it gets logged (with original cause) and converted into a useful message for the end user.

This only applies to exceptions that cannot be handled (which is most). There are other cases for things like connection retries, but I don't think that's the primary point of your question.

Answer (score 3):

In a single catch block, EITHER handle (which could be as simple as just logging) OR throw (rethrowing the exception, or wrapping it and throwing the new exception), never both.

Wrapping is not a problem, because if you look at the stacktraces, frames are not repeated. The causes only contain the frames below the wrap.

Comment: How would you throw a wrapped exception AND rethrow the original? You can only throw one exception.

Comment: You would throw the new exception that wraps the old. Editing my post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Checked exceptions usually aren't worth the troubles they cause.

My favorite way to get a checked exception up the tree to where it can be handled is to wrap it once as an unchecked exception and let it fly.

You could also just use the throws clause in each method.

Or you trap it at a low level and actually handle it and return it as an error code.

The very best way to handle exceptions is to never generate them. (For instance if you are trying to open a file that may or may not exist, rather than opening it then creating it if the open fails, test it, create it if necessary THEN open it and avoid the exception altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't catch and wrap unless you think you are adding some value by doing so.  In which case you want each layer to appear in the logs.  Any layers you don't want, don't put them there.

If you have not control over the wrapping, you can un-wrap and discard them, or just put up with them being in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

It may be best to do this using a multiple approaches:

- Try not to catch every exception, instead declare your methods/constructors to throw these exception and catch them from code higher up the call chain.  There is little point in catching and re-throwing unless you need to close resources (such as database handles.)
- Extend your own exception class and chain other exceptions into it.  While you are at it, include a state variable in your Exception class to see if it was already logged or not.

Comment: Closing a resource should probably be done in a finally block. Rolling back a transaction may be a better example of what to do in a catch block.